# Popping an array is popping another array DFS recursion

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

This is the question

```
Given an array of distinct integers candidates and a target integer target, return a list of all unique combinations of candidates where the chosen numbers sum to target. You may return the combinations in any order.

The same number may be chosen from candidates an unlimited number of times. Two combinations are unique if the frequency of at least one of the chosen numbers is different.

It is guaranteed that the number of unique combinations that sum up to target is less than 150 combinations for the given input.
```

For some reason when I pop my `path`, it also pops my `ret` value and I end up with 2 empty arrays. Why is it when I pop `path`, it messes with my `ret` array? Answer should be `[[2, 2, 3], [7]]`

```
def dfs(nums, target, path, ret, start):
if target < 0:
    return
if target == 0:
    new_path = path
    ret.append(new_path)
    return
for i in range(start,len(nums)):
    path.append(nums[i])
    dfs(nums, target - nums[i], path, ret, i)
    path.pop()

def combinationSum(candidates, target):
    ret = []
    dfs(candidates, target, [], ret, 0)
    print(ret)
    return ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    combinationSum([2, 3, 6, 7], 7)
```

I'm following this solution on Leetcode but the part where it says `path+[nums[i]]` doesn't make sense to me. Don't you have to pop?

```
class Solution(object):
def combinationSum(self, candidates, target):
    ret = []
    self.dfs(candidates, target, [], ret)
    return ret

def dfs(self, nums, target, path, ret):
    if target < 0:
        return 
    if target == 0:
        ret.append(path)
        return 
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        self.dfs(nums[i:], target-nums[i], path+[nums[i]], ret)
```

Comment: you append the path list into ret. So ret now has an element that point to the same list as path. So when you pop from path then of course the value in ret changes since its the same list

Comment: How would I fix this issue? I have tried to assign path to something else (ex. new_path = path. ret.append(new_path) ) before I append it, but that doesn't solve my issue either.

Comment: `new_path = path` just makes another name to access the same list that path points to. If you want to take a shallow copy of the list you can just do `new_path = path[:]` to take a shallow copy

Comment: Does this only apply to list? What else does this apply to? Whats the difference between this and say a normal variable like x = 5; b = x; b =4. This doesn't change x to 4.

Comment: you should look at understanding `muatble` vs `immutable` things like lists and dicts etc are mutable, that means once they are allocated in memory, you can change them. However immutable objects like str, or int etc are immutable, meaning once you set them in memory they cant be changed.

Comment: In your example, when you do `b = x` you are just telling python to point b at what ever x points to. I.E 5. However you then do `b = 4`.  this then tells python make a new object for 4 and point b at it. So now b does not point to the same object as x. the same issue would happen with lists. if you done `path = [1,2]; new_path = path; new_path = [3, 4]` the same thing would happen, new_path would firs tpoint to the list that path points to, however you then make a new list and point new_path to it, so new_path now doesnt point to the same list as path does.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we have a `path` and a `next_path` which is `path+[nums[i]]`. We can just print it out so that we'd see how it works:

```
from typing import List
import collections
import itertools
import functools
import math
import string
import random
import bisect
import re
import operator
import heapq
import queue

from queue import PriorityQueue
from itertools import combinations, permutations
from functools import lru_cache
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict
from collections import deque
from collections import Counter


class Solution:
    def combinationSum(self, candidates, target):
        combinations = []
        candidates.sort()

        def depth_first_search(candidates, target, index, path, combinations):
            if target < 0:
                return

            if target == 0:
                combinations.append(path)
                return

            for iteration in range(index, len(candidates)):
                if (candidates[iteration] > target):
                    break
                print(f'{path} path at iteration {iteration}')
                next_path = path + [candidates[iteration]]
                print(f'{next_path} next path at iteration {iteration}')
                depth_first_search(candidates, target - candidates[iteration], iteration, next_path, combinations)

        depth_first_search(candidates, target, 0, [], combinations)
        return combinations


print(Solution().combinationSum(candidates = [2, 3, 6, 7], target = 7))
# print(Solution().combinationSum(candidates = [2,3,5], target = 8)) #
# print(Solution().combinationSum(candidates = [2], target = 1)) #
# print(Solution().combinationSum(candidates = [1], target = 1)) #
# print(Solution().combinationSum(candidates = [1], target = 2)) #
```

#### Output

```
[] path at iteration 0
[2] next path at iteration 0
[2] path at iteration 0
[2, 2] next path at iteration 0
[2, 2] path at iteration 0
[2, 2, 2] next path at iteration 0
[2, 2] path at iteration 1
[2, 2, 3] next path at iteration 1
[2] path at iteration 1
[2, 3] next path at iteration 1
[] path at iteration 1
[3] next path at iteration 1
[3] path at iteration 1
[3, 3] next path at iteration 1
[] path at iteration 2
[6] next path at iteration 2
[] path at iteration 3
[7] next path at iteration 3
[[2, 2, 3], [7]]
```